# actionscript 3 how to keep track of time elapsed?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, timer

im new to actionscript3 flash. I have a int variable and i would like to add +2 every second since game started. How can i do this ? how do i know how much time has elapsed? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

getTimer() will return an int of exactly how many milliseconds from when flash started.

```
import flash.utils.getTimer;

var myInt:int = getTimer() * 0.001;
```

myInt will now be however many seconds the program has been running.

edit: oh to tell how long it has been running just keep the initial myInt and check it against the current timer.

so when the game first starts.

```
var startTime:int = getTimer();
```

then every frame or whenever you need to check it.

```
var currentTime:int = getTimer();


var timeRunning:int = (currentTime - startTime) * 0.001; // this is how many seconds the game has been running.
```

Comment: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as2/reference/flashlite/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118cd9b5f6e-7a54.html

there is little ambiguity, I see in the IDE's getTimer returning int while flash documentation says getTimer returns Number. Would be usefull to know wich one is correct. cheers

Comment: the function declaration in the headers (library) is "public function getTimer():int" so it returns an int. by the way those are the actionScript 2 references not the actionScript 3 ones. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#getTimer()

Comment: you saved me headhackes :)

Comment: Your example is faulty:

var myInt:int = getTimer() * 0.001; 

myInt will always be 0, because you cast an unassigned Number to an int

Answer (score 1):

```
var a:int = 0;

var onTimer:Function = function (e:TimerEvent):void {
    a += 2;
}

var timer:Timer = new Timer(1000);
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onTimer);
timer.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var countdown:Timer = new Timer(1000);
countdown.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerHandler);
countdown.start();

function timerHandler(e:TimerEvent):void
{           
    var minute = Math.floor(countdown.currentCount /  60);
    if(minute < 10)
        minute = '0'+minute;

    var second = countdown.currentCount % 60;
    if(second < 10)
        second = '0'+second;


    var timeElapsed = minute +':'+second;
    trace(timeElapsed);
}
```