# AS3 Dynamic Text

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

Im new to ActionScript 3 and am trying to get a number to deplete when i start a timer

So far ive got it so you click the button 'btngo' and a timer begins whilst the ball object moves.

I also want a dynamic text that starts at 100 to deplete down to 0 in 10 seconds when this button is clicked, but unfortunately i have no clue how to do it

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thank you :)

```
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;

stop();


var timer1:Timer = new Timer (10,10000);
var timer2:Timer = new Timer (10,10000);
timer1.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, forward);
timer2.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, back);
btngo.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, green);
btnstop.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, red);

function green(e:MouseEvent):void {
    timer2.stop();
    timer1.start();
    trace("timer started");
}

function red(e:MouseEvent):void {
    timer1.stop();
    timer2.start();
    trace("timer started");
}

function forward(e:TimerEvent):void {
    ball.x += 2;
}

function back(e:TimerEvent):void {
    ball.x -= 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, here are two functions which will get you what you are looking for. This first one is the creation of the text:

```
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.text.TextFieldType;

var dynamic_text:TextField;
function CreateText()
{
    // You can also replace this part with code that creates a textfield that you have in your library,
    // in that case just make sure the textfield is set to dynamic in the textfield properties

    // Create a new textfield.
    dynamic_text = new TextField();

    // Make sure its type is set to Dynamic.
    dynamic_text.type = TextFieldType.DYNAMIC;

    // Position it somewhere on the screen.
    dynamic_text.x = 10;
    dynamic_text.y = 10;

    // Set a default text for now.
    dynamic_text.text = "Time: " + time_left;

    // Make sure the players cannot select the text.
    dynamic_text.selectable = false;

    // Add it to your stage (or other parent, take your pick)
    stage.addChild(dynamic_text);
}
```

This second one is called every TimerEvent:

```
function OnTimerChange()
{
    // Update the text based on the new time.
    dynamic_text.text = "Time: " + time_left;
}
```

You will have to call this OnTimerChange function inside your own "forward" and "backward" functions, and in those two functions you will have to calculate how much time has passed.

For an example how to keep track of time that has passed since you pressed a button:
[actionscript 3 how to keep track of time elapsed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489980/actionscript-3-how-to-keep-track-of-time-elapsed)

Hope this helped.